# Populate Text Input With Form Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple html form where I input a title and description and hit submit.  At the top of the page are some paragraphs of text that I often copy and paste into these fields.  It's a repetitive task, and the paragraphs are generated dynamically with php.

Can I put a button or link at the end of each paragraph or div that would fill in my form input fields with a script?  Then all I would have to do is hit submit. I'm already using jquery on the page too.

EDIT:

```
<p>Sentence one.  Longer than this</p><!--would like a button here to populate field in form below-->
<p>Sentence two.  Longer than this</p>
<p>Sentence three.  Longer than this</p>

<form id="sampleform" action="actionpage.php" method="post">
Title<input type="text" name="title>
Desc<input type="text" name="title>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Comment: Can you give us some code to look at?

Comment: It has info I don't want to share, but I'll whip up a sample.

Comment: Added the basic setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some selector that can select all of the `<p>` tags that contain those paragraphs, you can do something like the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var $descInput = $('input[name=desc]');
  // wrap the text of each paragraph in a span so we can target it easily.
  // Then add a button inside each <p> at the end that will prepopulate that text.
  $('p.prefill').wrapInner('<span class="text"></span>').append('<button class="prefill-sentence">Prefill</button>');
  // Add a click handler for all the newly added buttons
  $('button.prefill-sentence').click(function() {
    // get the contents of the span we used to wrap the sentence with
    var sentence = $(this).prev('.text').text();
    // add that sentence to the current value of the description input
    $descInput.val($descInput.val() + sentence);
  });
});
```

```css
.prefill-sentence {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="prefill">Sentence one. Longer than this</p>
<p class="prefill">Sentence two. Longer than this</p>
<p class="prefill">Sentence three. Longer than this</p>
<form id="sampleform" action="actionpage.php" method="post">
  Title
  <input type="text" name="title" />Desc
  <input type="text" name="desc" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

(Note I assumed you had a name of "desc" for your description input. Ideally, you can use a class or id to target it easier in the real code).

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about the buttons appending text, so I could use more than one.  But that makes my page more useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://plnkr.co/edit/S3OegSh80UH6oQJPDatr?p=preview

```js
$(function(){
  $('p').each(function(){
      $(this).after('<button>Click<\/button>');    
    });
    
    $('button').on('click', function(){
      var txt = $(this).prev().text();
      $('input').eq(0).val(txt);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to add something more specific to those php-generated paragraphs/divs, so they can safely be selected and manipulated by JS.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwJwmO

### HTML

```
<div class="text-section">
  Sentence one.  Longer than this
</div>
<div class="text-section">
  Sentence two.  Longer than this
</div>
<div class="text-section">
  Sentence three.  Longer than this
</div>

<form id="sampleform" action="actionpage.php" method="post">
  Title<input type="text" name="title">
  Desc<input type="text" name="desc">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### JS

```
var $text_section = $('.text-section');
var $description_field = $('input[name="desc"]');

$text_section.each(function(){

  var section_text = $(this).text();

  var $autofill_button = $('<button>Autofill</button>');

  $autofill_button.click(function(){
    $description_field.val(section_text);
  });

  $(this).append($autofill_button);

});
```

Comment: Advocating the use of globals by not using `var` will not lead to good JS habits. Also, your buttons do not append to the input, they will replace its existing contents.

Comment: Leaving off var was an oversight - too much switching between PHP and JS today,  From how I read the question, it seems like he wanted the contents replaced rather than appended.

Comment: That's understandable. I just wanted to make sure anyone learning off your code was aware that omitting var was a risky thing to do.

Comment: I actually did mean for the text to be replaced.  But now that I think of it, appending is useful for me too.  I will see going forward with this repetitive task which one ends up being the useful one more often.  Might take what you all have given me and try to make two buttons after each div.  Append and replace.  Thanks all for the good info.

Comment: The vars are now there.